# MS-Access SubForm entry decides which table to write to

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access

What i need today is the following:

I have built a form, and i have several tables where that form can write to, how can i make this selectable upon opening the form? Im thinking that basically, before opening the form, i should choose in another form the table to write to, the thing is, the list of tables to write to is not fixed, i have a form that is used to create tables.

For example, i create table x and table y and table w, which are equal in structure and field names and everything, it just changes the table name itself and the values in the fields. how do i tell the form i have that it must write on table x until closing the form and then after closing, when i am to open again, it asks again which table to write to and writes to it until i close the form. Then i decide to create table u and the next time i open the form, table u must be in the list, how feasible is this and how should i approach it?

I already have a table that communicates with the form for creating a new table, hence, keeping a record of every table created, so, i can get the name of the table i want to write to, my problem now is how to change the origin of control in the form, can this be done from code?

Answer (score 1):

On opening of the form you can loop through the tables collection DAO.TableDefs
and fill a listbox with the tableDeft's names.
When the user selects a table name, you set the form's record source to the table name.

Comment: alright, that sounds good, what can i do to list only tables with a specific name (the name is the same, it only changes the number after, eg.: PF 00, PF 01, PF 34<--Like this  because i have other tables that shouldnt be selectable from the combobox)

Comment: @Antero: Something like 'foreach tableDef tdf in tableDefs'   if left(pdf.SourceTableName,2)="PF" call AddToList(tdf.SourceTableName)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly look into creating a list with a query something like:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name 
FROM MsysObjects 
WHERE (Left$([Name],1)<>"~") 
AND 
    (Left$([Name],4) <> "Msys") 
AND (MSysObjects.Type)=1 
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

MSysObjects can get you a list of objects in the database. 
Keep in mind, if you have a backend that supplies the tables via linked table manager, you will need to use this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE Databse <> '';
```

Using this method you can populate a control using this query as the record source. Then, you can prompt the users direction and handle each table specifically and more explicitly.